# Contextual appropriateness for different tensor notations

Tags: notation, tensors

After listening to [Pavel Grinfeld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pavel_Grinfeld) tensor calculus [series of lectures on YT](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlXfTHzgMRULkodlIEqfgTS-H1AY_bNtq) I thought I kind of understood the notation until I read this question: [Relationship between covariant/contravariant basis vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/393316/994433), where the expression

$$V^i = M^{ij} V_j$$

triggered the following comments from knowledgeable contributors:

> 1. Unless I am missing something, this doesn't seem to be standard math notation, but rather some physics convention.
> 2. Yes, this is Einstein summation notation. The OP should be aware that notation and conventions differ here between mathematics and physics; the physics convention may be somewhat more convenient for computations but IMO physicists don't do a good job of explaining tensors.

This is not intended to be a facetious question, but I wish someone would spell out clearly what is accepted practice in Math, and what is Physics. Pavel Grindfeld certainly has glowing credentials as a mathematician, but it is possible that he used Physics notation if he was teaching engineers or physicists. However, this contraction of the covariant coefficients of a vector $V$ with the metric tensor to raise the index seems in line with his notation, except perhaps that instead of $g^{ij}$ there is $M^{ij}.$ Certainly it is understood that only the coefficients are included in the expression.

1. How would this expression be more "mathematical sounding"? If the Einstein notation wasn't used at all, and there was a $\Sigma,$ or if the Einstein notation was preserved, but no super-script indices were used, as in $V_i = g_{ij} V_j,$ or something entirely different?
2. To wrap up the Math/Physics tensor notation possible differences, is there also some distinguishing element in usage regarding the index spacing to denote order, as in $T^{\nu\mu}{}_{\gamma}$ versus $T^{\nu\mu}_{\gamma}$? Clearly this matters in something like this: $T_{i}{}^{a}{}_{j}{}^{b}{}_{k} = T_{imj}{}^{bd}g^{am}g_{kd} \ne T_{ijk}{}^{ab},$ as explained by Jackozee Hakkiuz [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2854074/994433).

Thank you!

Comment: Lol, we have done it from the same source. If you're continuing to follow Pavel's course, I suggest you check on Roger Penrose Road to reality book. He has a short two-three page exposition on tensor which I felt like really helped me get a prespective on tensors. Btw That course is clearly an engineering one. He himself says multipile times

Comment: Also one more book if you actually want to see the 'geometry' part of Differential Geometry is Visual Differential Geometry. I think in Pavels course an issue is that, he begins with the whole geometrical idea but after he gets to the derivatives, that idea of doing stuff by drawing pictures is pretty much forgotten. So, this book may help you retain interest through motivation from the visual part. In the end of the book, there is a section on Differential forms and tensors which I found very enlightening as well.